# Shouldn't the meta.webapps page link to the main webapps site?

Tags: discussion, links

Seems obvious to me.

Comment: Now there's a prominent link at the top of both parent and meta.  Thank you, webapps overlords!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to scroll all the way down and click the **parent site** link.

I'd prefer [an easier way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55551/easy-navigation-between-meta-and-parent-site) to get to it though.

**Update:** You should now see a link on the top left to toggle between the sites.